# How to add menu in Android without getting "R" error

Tags: android, menu

I am writing a simple application to get familiar with android programming. Today I want to play with menus. I follow [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)!. I first create "menu" folder under "res" and then add "game_menu.xml" in it. However this "R" thing can't get that folder. I tried some refresh to get it 'auto-generated' but it didn't work. I clean for a rebuild, but this time R.java completely dissappeared. How can I make eclipse to recreate R or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most likely misspelled something in your xml file, or have some other error. If the xml files are not entirely correct (or other resource files), the R. file cannot be built. Go through the file and make sure that everything is error free.
A common mistake is to name the resources with capitals, although the names can only contain small letters.
another common mistake is to use unsupported folder names.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the R is not creating the appropriate link for the menu?

To find your xml menu, you must type: "R.menu." & hit ctrl+space and all your menu's will pop up.

Try this way.

And if you want to check your R file, if its creating the menu link, search for:
"public static final class menu" in R file

In that class you will find your xml menu's..

Answer (score 2):

are you able to compile ? Check which R you have imported in your code. It should not be the android.R but the one from your project